# Event that fires when video is loaded and first frame is visible? Or how to crossfade two videos another way?

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I am trying to use video.js in a samsung smart tv application which unfortunately can only play one video at a time.

I need to simulate the smooth, preferably crossfade, transition between two videos. I am trying to do this by first fading in a screenshot of the next video and using that to cover up the screen while I switch video sources of the video.js plugin. When the player is ready I need to remove the screenshot.

The closest I have found is to remove the screenshot when "loadedmetadata" is called however I am still seeing an inconsistant blip of a black flash between the time the screenshot is removed and the video plays. This is very jarring and I need a consistent way to remove the screenshot only when the first frame has been loaded into the player.

Any other suggestions on how I could each a smooth transition between two videos while only using one video element would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not to involved in `html` anymore, but isn't it possible to layout two `video` elements above each other and fade out alpha from the `video` or `div` tag? I would check if this is possible..

Comment: Unfortunately the smart tv is only capable of playing one video at a time. If I layer two elements one of them will not play.

Answer (score 5):

I found the `loadeddata` event which, as described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadeddata) :

> The loadeddata event is fired when the first frame of the media has finished loading.

`loadedmetadata` only announce that media informations such as duration are loaded, but the `loadeddata` event should do the trick.

Comment: There is also the `playing` event if your video is going to auto-play.